# Why my optical limiting behavior is Descending? (on input intensity- output intensitydiagram)

Tags: optics, non-linear-optics, liquid-crystal

I measure some nonlinear optical materials and I know that output intensity respect to input intensity should be ascending like this diagram. but for me, for one of my materials, this diagram is Descending! others are ok. I don't know why? Is this need a physics knowledge that idk or that is my lab problem?
I used green laser. and my materials are liquid crystal
[Optical limiting](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/chemistry/optical-limiting)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have not given a whole lot of details, I will give some general lab advice.

1. Try reproducing the effect, preferably both by re-running the same sample in the same experiment, and making a new sample and re-running the experiment. These two quick checks can help orient you. If the same sample is producing different results, you may have made a mistake during the measurement. If a different sample of the same material is producing the correct behavior, falling in line with the rest of your samples, then I would assume the sample you have prepared was not made correctly.
2. If this behavior is reproducible between supposedly identical samples *and* measurements, then you may have yourself a physics question. Why is this sample behaving this way, unlike the others? Since I do not know what the differences are myself between your "odd sample out" and the others, I will have to leave the answer of that question to you.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, I tried this experiment with same sample and solved my problem. I found my problem. First one : my sample hadn't great quality, and two : I didn't use arm and 2nd detector to check input power. I moved sample on rail to mesure input and output power and repeat this way. Always laser beam should hit one place on sample surface. So, after moving sample, it changes beam place on surface! It means I meaured 2 or 3 points on sample and it's incorrect!